# Overlay translucent image on desktop / above all windows

Tags: kubuntu, display, kde, window, transparency

I want a translucent PNG overlayed on top of my screen (above all windows). I'm using this to mark a visible region while streaming.

So far I've figured out that `qiv -transparent filename.png` will add a mask to the window, but it's a boolean mask. I don't get translucent fading with the alpha channel.

I know several effects have opacity, and I can sent window opacity, so I'm hoping there's some way to display an image that way.

What program, tool, or widget can I use to blend an image onto the top of the desktop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was unable to find a stock solution so ended up modifying the `pqiv` program to achieve this.

I wrote an [article explaining details](https://mortoray.com/2018/08/04/creating-a-local-screen-overlay-for-streaming-obs-linux/).

The branch of `pqiv` is [here](https://github.com/phillipberndt/pqiv/pull/131). The command-line options for the desired effect are:

```
pqiv --click-through --keep-above --transparent-background --hide-info-box  filename.png
```

Comment: Make sure to use `./configure --gtk-version=3` if it won't build

Comment: I cloned from 'https://github.com/mortoray/pqiv', compiled it. --click-through and --keep-above are unknown options.... If i dont use them, it works

Comment: @VitorAbella make sure to checkout the correct feature branch
After cloning and going inside directory:
`git checkout feature/click-through`